# dialogflow Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Generator is already running

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I tested this code on my webOS emulator.
webOS emulator uses nodejs version 6.0.0

My code is here:

```
// The path to identify the agent that owns the created intent.
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

    let promise;

    for (const query of queries) {
        // The text query request.
        const request = {
                session: sessionPath,
                queryInput: {
                    text: {
                        text: query,
                        languageCode: languageCode,
                    },
                },
        };

        if (!promise) {
            // LOOK: this code is executed
            promise = sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
        } else {
            // ....
        }
    }emphasized text

    promise
    .then(responses => {
        // ....
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // error has occurred after detectIntent() is called.
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    });
```

Error message is here:
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Generator is already running

I don't know what this error means.
I refered this code. but dialogflow does not work.
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/detect.js